# django ioerror "failed to write data" "Exception occurred processing WSGI script"

Tags: python, django, wsgi, ioerror, django-wsgi

I'm running an django 1.8 application on Redhat's Openshift platform. The application provides RSS feeds and download of files. The files usually have more than 50MB. The problem is that when you try to download a file it's very likely that the download fails. Sometimes you're lucky and it runs through but (I guess) 80% of the downloads fail. They do not always fail at the same stage of progress, so sometimes you can download 10MB of the file sometimes 30MB.

I tried this on different machines, different browsers and even behind different internet connections. Happens everywhere.

I realised that when ever a failed download happens, there is an error in the log stating:

```
[Sat Apr 09 22:59:49 2016] [error] [client 127.9.XXX.XXX] mod_wsgi (pid=208430): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/lib/openshift/553BLABLABLA/app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi/application'.
[Sat Apr 09 22:59:49 2016] [error] [client 127.9.XXX.XXX] IOError: failed to write data
```

In this thread [How to prevent 'IOError: failed to write data' when client closes connection to Django/WSGI app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322578/how-to-prevent-ioerror-failed-to-write-data-when-client-closes-connection-to) they say, it's due to the client closing the connection. But I'm just downloading the file, why should the client close the connection unless it's finished?

Here's the content of my WSGI Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys

## GETTING-STARTED: make sure the next line points to your settings.py:
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'
## GETTING-STARTED: make sure the next line points to your django project dir:
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'], 'wsgi', 'myproject'))
virtenv = os.environ['APPDIR'] + '/virtenv/'
## GETTING-STARTED: make sure the next line has the right python version:
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = os.path.join(virtenv, 'lib/python2.7/site-packages')
virtualenv = os.path.join(virtenv, 'bin/activate_this.py')
try:
    execfile(virtualenv, dict(__file__=virtualenv))
except:
    pass

import django.core.wsgi
application = django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: I am still facing this issue. I would really like to publish this web application now, but this problem is preventing me from doing so.

I did some more research: Same happens when I use wget instead of a browser to download a file.

I tried to download the file with wget from an digitalocean (www.digitalocean.com) machine and it works. I suppose it's because it downloads the file very fast within 3 or 4 seconds.

Anybody any hints on how to track down this problem? I would really appreciate

Comment: I tried out setting the project in productive mode by setting DEBUG = False and editing the media / static file handling.
Now I facing less trouble when downloading files from my application. However the problems still exist. It seems that when I try downloading files with a slow internet connection (like less than 2Mbit) it's still nearly impossible to get the files from the app. But with faster connections it works quite nice. I'm trying to track down this issue more verbose logs - see my other [question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40075690/verbose-logging-in-django-on-openshift)

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton mentioned this (answer and comment was deleted):  
OpenShift 2 will timeout a request in the front end router if it runs more than 60 seconds from what I remember. So if the download takes long than that because of a slow client, the connection will be dropped by the front end router. This will cause your web application to see the connection as being closed and you can get that error.

Comment: This statement also means that I cannot solve this since it is the timeout setting in Openshift and I use the Openshift on rhcloud.com. Did I get this right?